# There is a way to group sliders in Xamarin.Forms to change value toghether?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin

I'm trying to group various sliders elements to work together. In example if I have two elements, both are set to 50 (values goes from  0 to 100), the sum of the values must be always 100, so if I set one of the sliders to value 70, the other one must decrease dynamically to 30 value.

```
<ListView x:Name="listView"
          ItemSource="myList">
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <ViewCell>
               <Slider x:Name="slider"
                       Maximum="100"
                       Minimum="0"
                       Value="{Binding MyValue}"
                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                       MinimumTrackColor="Black"
                       MaximumTrackColor="Black"
                       ThumbColor="{StaticResource myColor}"
                       ValueChanged="OnValueChanged"
                       PropertyChanging="ChangingSliderValue"/>
               <Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference slider}, Path=Value, StringFormat='{0:0}'}"
                      FontSize="Medium"
                      FontAttributes="Bold"
                      HorizontalOptions="End"
                      WidhtRequest="40"/>
           </ViewCell>
       </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The C# class of my objects is

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private int _value;
    private string _name;
    private bool _someBool;

    public int MyValue { get {return _value;} set {_value = value;} }
    public string Name { get {return _name;} set {_name = value;} }
    public bool SomeBool { get {return _someBool;} set {_someBool = value; OnPropertyChanged();} }

    void OnPropertyChanged ([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

And part of the class of the Xaml page is:

```
namespace MyApp
{
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class SliderPage: ContentPage
{
    private ObservableCollection<MyClass> list = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();
    ...

    public SliderPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitList();
        listView.ItemsSource = list;
        ...
    }

    private void InitList () ...

    private void ChangingSliderValue (object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Code to stick together the slider...
    }
}
```

Any suggestion of how to achieve my goal?

Comment: Use the Slider.ValueChanged event: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.slider.valuechanged?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: Mmm I used both, `Slider.ValueChanged` event first and `Slider.ChangingValue` then and the result is the same and is not working.

The logic I wrote, few minutes ago, work but is not showing dynamically:

in the `InitList()` I add the line `myClass.PropertyChanged += ChangedValue` (to know of wich objetc I'm changing the value).
Then in the `Slider.ChangingValue` I wrote the logic to decrease the value of the others object but it isn't show but if I change page, the slider position change according to the values. I need to show it while changing, not if  I refresh the page.

Comment: Does it work now ?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I'm trying, I'm adapting the code just now, thank you so much for your help. Your example is exactly what I want.

Comment: Don't forget to accept it if it helps you :
)

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Work perfectly, you made my day man! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> work but is not showing dynamically

You need to implement the interface **INotifyPropertyChanged** on property **MyValue** so that the element will update in runtime .

By the way , since you had used data binding in your project . It would be better to handle logic in ViewModel. So you could modify the code like following

#### in Xmal

```
 <ListView 
          ItemsSource="{Binding MySource}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HeightRequest="300" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <Slider x:Name="slider"
                       Maximum="100"
                       Minimum="0"
                       Value="{Binding MyValue,Mode=TwoWay}"
                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                       MinimumTrackColor="Black"
                       MaximumTrackColor="Black"/>
                            
                      <Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference slider}, Path=Value, StringFormat='{0:0}'}"
                      FontSize="20"
                      FontAttributes="Bold"             
                      WidthRequest="40"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

#### in Code behind

Model

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public int Id { get; set; }  // add this property to index the slider

    private int _value;
    private string _name;
    private bool _someBool;

    public int MyValue {
     
         get
        {
            return _value;
        }

        set
        {
            if(_value!=value)
            {
                _value = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MyValue");
            }
        }
    
    }
    public string Name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; } }
    public bool SomeBool { get { return _someBool; } set { _someBool = value; OnPropertyChanged("SomeBool"); } }

    void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyClass> MySource { get; set; }


    bool isFirstLoad = true;

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        MySource = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>() { 
        
            new MyClass(){MyValue = 50,Id=0 },
            new MyClass(){MyValue = 50,Id=1 },

        };

        

        foreach (MyClass model in MySource)
        {
            model.PropertyChanged += Model_PropertyChanged;
        }

       
    }

    private void Model_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        
        if (e.PropertyName== "MyValue")
        {
            //handle your logic here as you need 
            MyClass model = sender as MyClass;

                foreach (MyClass item in MySource)
                {
                    if (model.Id != item.Id)
                    {
                        item.MyValue = 100 - model.MyValue;  
                    }
                }
           

        }
    }
}
```

#### ContentPage

```
public xxxPage()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   BindingContext = new MyViewModel();
}
```

[image]